# intellij webstorm : how to associate files with left side navigation window

Tags: javascript, node.js, webstorm

Like eclipse, when I use curtain file, left side navigation wiondow will move to the file structure automatically. It makes me very easy to tell where does this file belong to.

In webstorm, is there a way to enable this feature?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use autoscroll from source setting:[image]